# How do i retrieve data from Async storage and use it in my component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have saved a user_id and token in Async storage and i can retrieve it in via console log. with the retrive function. So i know the set function is working perfectly, the functions in deviceStorage all Async.

The problem comes when trying to use the retrieved user_id & token in my component it returns undefined.

How can i get an item from storage and use it later in my code, i want to use the token and userid for a fetch request. Please help me and highlight the best way to do.

```
    import deviceStorage from "../components/services/deviceStorage";
    class Jobs extends Component {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
       jobsData: [],
       isLoading: true
       };
      }

    componentDidMount() {


        deviceStorage.retrieveToken().then(token => {
            this.setState({
               token: token
                 });
        });

        deviceStorage.retrieveUserId().then(user_id => {
            this.setState({
               user_id: user_id
             });
        });


const opts = {
  method: "GET",

  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Token " + this.state.token
  }
};

fetch("http://example.com/job/" + this.user_id, opts)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(jobs => {
    this.setState({
      jobsData: jobs,
      isLoading: false
    });
    console.log(jobsData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  }

  render {}
```

Code for the retrieve and set

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


const deviceStorage = {
    async storeItem(key, item) {
        try {
            //we want to wait for the Promise returned by AsyncStorage.setItem()
            //to be resolved to the actual value before returning the value
            var jsonOfItem = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
            return jsonOfItem;
        } catch (error) {
           console.log(error.message);
        }
    },
    async retrieveItem(key) {
        try {
            const retrievedItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
            const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
           // console.log(item);
            return item;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        return
    }
};

export default deviceStorage;`
```

Comment: show the code for `retrieveToken` and `retrieveUserId`

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii i have updated the retrieve ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get the data stored in async storage:

(1) Promise method. Here your code does not wait for the block to finish and returns promise which is accompanied by **.then clause** if the promise resolves and **.catch clause** if there is error.

(2) Async and Await method. This is more preferred, here your code waits for the execution before proceeding one of the example to refer is below:

```
retrieveData() {
 AsyncStorage.getItem("id").then(value => {
        if(value == null){
             //If value is not set or your async storage is empty
        }
        else{
             //Process your data 
        }
      })
        .catch(err => {
            // Add some error handling
  });
```

Second Method example:

```
async retrieveData() {
try {
 let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("id");
 if (value !== null) {
  //you have your data in value variable
  return value;
 }
}
catch (error) {
// Error retrieving data
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

your retrieve data storage methods should look like this

```
retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      return value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous solutions

```
//function to retrieve data
async function retrieveItem(key) {
 try {
  const retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(key); //dataType String
   const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);//dataType object
   return item;
 }  catch (error) {
   console.log(error.message);
 }
 return
}

//function call
retrieveItem(key).then((value) => {
          //unlike normal function call, this waits for the promise to complete
          return value;// actual value not the promise
          })
          .catch((error) => {
             console.log('Error: ' + error);
          });
```